Parcel relative path for HTML includes
- projectFolder
  |-src
    |- index.html
    |- nav.html
    |- aboutUs
      |- index.html
    |- images
      |- logo.svg

Above you can see my project structure which I use to finally bundle it all using Parcel.js
I'm using posthtml-include plugin to insert nav.html into index.html
nav.html file also uses image ./images/logo.svg
It all works fine.
But I also want file ./aboutUs/index.html to use same nav.html from upper directory. Problem is that upper directory nav.html file has relation to ./images/logo.svg which doesn't work when file from lower directory ./aboutUs/index.html is packed.
How to resolve this so all files, no matter how deep into directory structure, could include same nav.html from root of ./src
Help me configure either package.json or required paths or show me any other solution you may have.
